# Lookup field populated, additional fields still empty

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column

I added a lookup field to one of my custom lists and I selected a few additional fields to display. I then opened the list, created a test entry but the "additional fields" are still empty even though the lookup field is populated.

For example:

List 1 - Client Name, Address, E-mail

List 2 - Invoice #, Client Name, Client Name:Address, Client Name:E-mail

I have a bunch of data in List 1 filled out already. I went to List 2 and created a new invoice record, selected one of my records from List 1 in the drop down for Client Name, but "Client Name:Address" and "Client Name:E-mail" stay blank. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Crisis adverted -- apparently it's a bug in SharePoint designer. For anyone else who stumbles across this post, you need to edit the column in your browser and select the additional fields you want to add. Although the additional fields were checked in SharePoint designer and it DOES create read-only columns, apparently Designer doesn't actually link them to anything.